# Adding Braintree to an Angular 2 app using SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs, braintree

We have a large Angular 2 project that uses SystemJS. We want to incorporate Braintree in this project, however, I'm getting SystemJS 404 errors.

As I've read, Braintree doesn't provide umd bundle with their npm package anymore. I've tried adding their *index.js* to the *systemjs.config.js* file, but it didn't work.

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/braintree-web/index.js/client
```

If I don't add anything I get the following error:

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/braintree-web
```

braintree-web is added to *package.json* and installed in *node_modules*

```
"@types/braintree-web": "^3.6.2"
"braintree-web": "^3.22.2"
```

Comment: how do you use that `braintree` in your project?

Comment: I tried declaring it (`declare var braintree: any;`), then the compilation passes, but the variable will be undefined. If I try importing the components I need (e.g.: `import {client} from "braintree-web";`) or requiring it (`let braintree = require('braintree-web');`), I get the exceptions written in the question.

Comment: how do you want to reference it in the application? from `window`?

Comment: Based on the Braintree dev docs, I'd use it like so:
`braintree.client.create({
      authorization: 'my-valid-key'
    }, function (err, instance) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(instance);
    });
`